# Merging and subtracting DataFrame columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame, something like:

```
col1  col2 col3 col5
NaN    1    2    8
2     NaN   4    8
4     NaN   4    8
```

I want to do two things:

1) Merge columns 1 and 2:

```
newcol1 col3 col5
1       2    8
2       4    8
4       4    8
```

I have tried using .concat, but that just concatenates the rows. Doesn't seem like I can use standard `+` operators with NaN values.

2) Subtract column 5 from new column 1 and column 3, so I end up with:

```
newcol1    col3
-7         -6
-6         -4
-4         -4
```

Tried doing it this way:

```
dataframe[['newcol1', 'col2']] - dataframe['col5']
```

and

```
dataframe[['newcol1', 'col2']].subtract(dataframe['col5'])
```

but neither works.

Answer (score 13):

To get the new column, you could use `fillna` (or `combine_first`):

```
df['newcol1'] = df.col1.fillna(df.col2)
```

Then for the subtraction, use `sub` and specify `axis=0` since we want to consider the row indices when matching up labels (not the column indices as is the default):

```
>>> df[['newcol1', 'col3']].sub(df['col5'], axis=0)
   newcol1  col3
0       -7    -6
1       -6    -4
2       -4    -4
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong - when I use fillna, it just replaces all rows of col2 with col1.

Comment: @user1566200 - that's puzzling, it should return the correct result. Which version of Pandas are you using? Does `df.col1.combine_first(df.col2)` work any better?

Comment: Also, when using .sub, I get the error: "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (320,) (80,) "

Comment: @ajcr That does the same thing. How do I check pandas version?

Comment: @user1566200: I'm not sure why that error is popping up if you're subtracting columns from the same DataFrame. Does it work alright on the example in your question?

Comment: Looks like I'm using Version 0.15.2

Comment: Did exactly my example above and tried your suggestion, still just makes newcol1 a duplicate of col1, and the .sub operation gives me the error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (3,) "

Comment: For the `fillna` thing, the only possible cause I can think of is that your DataFrame has duplicate indices. The subtraction shouldn't raise any error if you're subtracted columns in the same DataFrame (...I've no idea what's going on...).

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach.

You could create `newcol1` by `sum(axis=1)`

```
In [256]: df['newcol1'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].sum(axis=1)

In [257]: df
Out[257]:
   col1  col2  col3  col5  newcol1
0   NaN     1     2     8        1
1     2   NaN     4     8        2
2     4   NaN     4     8        4
```

Then use `df.sub()` on `axis=0`

```
In [258]: df[['newcol1', 'col3']].sub(df['col5'], axis=0)
Out[258]:
   newcol1  col3
0       -7    -6
1       -6    -4
2       -4    -4
```

Comment: So bizarre. When I do the first line above, I get newcol1 as a column of all 0s.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [58]:

df['newcol'] = df[['col1','col2']].sum(axis=1) - df['col5']
df['col3'] = df['col3'] - df['col5']
df
Out[58]:
   col1  col2  col3  col5  newcol
0   NaN     1    -6     8      -7
1     2   NaN    -4     8      -6
2     4   NaN    -4     8      -4
```

You can then drop col1 and col2:

```
In [59]:

df = df.drop(['col1','col2'],axis=1)
df
Out[59]:
   col3  col5  newcol
0    -6     8      -7
1    -4     8      -6
2    -4     8      -4
```

Comment: This gets the subtraction correct, but my 'newcol1' is a column of NaNs

Comment: You'll have to post full data in order for everyone to reproduce this