# Add calculated column to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Guys I just started using python and having issue using the pandas dataframe.

[image]

I have dataframe in the above format. I have function to calculate distance between the locations.

```
def Dist(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2): 
dlat = lat2 - lat1   
dlon = lon2 - lon1
return dlat + dlon
```

I want to create a new column on the dataframe for each distance from lat1/lon1 to lat/lon and lat2/lon2 to lat/lon. I tried with the following code but getting the error.

```
df['dist1'] = Dist(df['lat'], df['lon'], df['lat1'], df['lon1'] )
df['dist2'] = Dist(df['lat'], df['lon'], df['lat2'], df['lon2'] )

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

What am I missing here? what would be the way to call the function for each row and add that as the value for each cell in the new column?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: First bit of help I'll offer is to suggest you read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It helps you lay out your question in a way that the people who answer questions are willing to respond favorably to.

Comment: @piRSquared agreed. And in this case, it's important you actually give use your function, not `return something`

Comment: @piRSquared thanks for the suggestion. The function is not that important here, you can just return 0 and you will still get the issue. However instead of returning 'something' I am returning some real value now. My problem is when I call the method, the whole series is being passed to the function. I am sorry if my question is not complete or understandable.

Comment: @Bikswan actually, the function *and the dataframe* are of *critical importance*. Using random data with a dataframe with the same column names and the same function returns what you would expect without an error. Are you, by chance, using the `float()` function in your `Dist` function?

Comment: You can also read/try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832455/merging-and-subtracting-dataframe-columns-in-pandas

Comment: If you are using `float()` you should use something like `lat.astype(float)` instead

Comment: type error is because my function is expecting the float and I am passing the dataframe series. But how to call the function for each row while adding the column is my real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way. May not be efficient though.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'dist_1'] =  Dist(row['lat'], row['lon'], row['lat1'], row['lon1'])
    df.loc[index, 'dist_2'] =  Dist(row['lat'], row['lon'], row['lat2'], row['lon2'])
```